# How to modify a json list with jsonata

Tags: list, object, if-statement, conditional-statements, jsonata

I have the following:

```
[{"result":"SUCCESS"}, {"result":"FAILURE"}, {"result":"SUCCESS"}]
```

I would like to transform with jsonata that into:
[1,0,1]

BR,

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using jsonata

Answer (score 1):

```
$.(result = "SUCCESS" ? 1 : 0)
```

See https://try.jsonata.org/g_qF8wPAw